# Min function while using strings in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, min

I'm using chisquare test for my data. I'm appending them in a loop in that way:
My `.txt` file looks like below, it has 180 rows with strings like that. Now I want to find the minimum value from those 180 rows, which is contained in parentesis, like in example below `(15.745037950673217,)`, but I don't want to lose information which is assigned to a string in that row, which is `201701241800 Chi for 75 degree model`.

```
...
201701241800 Chi for 75 degree model (15.745037950673217,)
201701241800 Chi for 76 degree model (16.014744332924252,)
...
```

The code I use looks like this:

```
o = chisquare(f_obs=fin, f_exp=y)
rows = str(Date) + str(Start_time_hours_format) + str(Start_time_minutes_format) + " Chi for {} degree model ".format(r) + str(o[0:1])
table.append(rows)
```

The problem is that number of those calculations is enormously huge. My task is to find minimum value in each iteration, which is defined by a for loop. Example above came from one iteration (There are 180 degree models in each iteration). The problem is I cannot use `min(table)` because I've got there strings, but I cannot erase them, because that information is important. Do you have any ideas how to find min value here? I mean specificly min value in parentesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found a way to solve this problem. Code below:

```
    o = chisquare(f_obs=fin, f_exp=y)
    rows = str(Date) + str(Start_time_hours_format) + str(Start_time_minutes_format) + " Chi for {} degree model ".format(r) + str(o[0:1])
    print(rows)
    table.append(rows)

with open('measurements.txt', 'a') as j:
    j.write(min(table))
    j.write('\n')
    j.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list `lst`, `min(lst)` returns the minimum value without modifying the list. If you don't have a list, but objects from which you want to consider a value, let's say `obj[i].myvalue`, then you can do something like

```
min = 1000 # a huge number much bigger than your expected values
for o in obj:
    if o.myvalue < min:
        min = o.myvalue
```

which assigns to `min` the minimum value (probably it is not the best way, but it works for sure).

[I would be more specific, but it is not clear what kind of object you have to find the minimum of. Please consider to update your question to be more explicative.]